# Mathematical curve to represent a contour plot of a bimodal distribution in two dimensions

Tags: graphing-functions, curves

I am attempting to find a mathematical curve $f(x,y)$ that describes approximately the contour plot of a bimodal constructed from two Gaussian distributions centered at $(0, \pm y_0)$ and $\sigma = 1$.

The curve $f(x,y)$ should resemble an ellipsis for points near and far away from $(0, \pm y_0)$ and transform into a type of [Lemniscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate) for points in between.

As an example, see the following picture with $y_0 = 1.3$: [image]

---

**Code to generate the image**:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

#Draw the bimodal distribution
N = int(1e8)
y_0 = 1.3
rng = np.random.default_rng(1)
x_g = rng.normal(size=2*N)
y_g = np.concatenate([rng.normal(loc = y_0, size=N), rng.normal(loc = -y_0, size=N)])

#Bins
x_max = 3
Bins_x =  np.linspace(-x_max, x_max, 100)
Bins_y =  np.linspace(-x_max, x_max, 100)
binCenter_x = (Bins_x[1:]+Bins_x[:-1])/2
binCenter_y = (Bins_y[1:]+Bins_y[:-1])/2

#Construct histogram
z_counts, edges  = np.histogramdd((x_g, y_g), bins = [Bins_x, Bins_y])

#Plot
im = plt.pcolormesh(binCenter_x, binCenter_y, z_counts.T, cmap = 'plasma_r', zorder = -1,rasterized=True)#,  norm = LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=np.max(z_counts)))
plt.contour(binCenter_x, binCenter_y, gaussian_filter(z_counts, sigma=0.5).T, levels=10)
plt.colorbar(im, label = 'Counts')
plt.gca().set_aspect(1./plt.gca().get_data_ratio())
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.savefig('bimodal.png', dpi = 300)
```

Comment: Why $\sigma=0$? From the code it looks like $\sigma=1$

Comment: @Andrei You are right, is $\sigma = 1$. I changed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curves you are describing are conceptually identical to the Cassinian oval, as described in *A Catalog of Special Plane Curves*, J. Dennis Lawrence, Dover, 1972, pp. 153-154. A description can also be found [here](https://www.2dcurves.com/quartic/quarticca.html).

The Cartesian equation of these curves is given by

$$
(x^2+y^2+a^2)^2=b^4+4a^2x^2
$$

and the polar equation is

$$
r^4-2a^2r^2\cos2\theta=b^4-a^4
$$

These curves have the property that if $a=b$ the oval is lemniscate of Bernoulli. If $a<b$, there is one loop, and if $a\ge b$, two loops. The only difference between your curves and these is a $90^{\circ}$ rotation.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

Comment: @Cye Waldman: Cassinian Ovals are loci of constant product of distances from two foci. How are they related to  bimodals of two Gaussian distributions?

Comment: @Narasimham That's a good question, but, unfortunately, beyond my ken. I was merely giving the OP an opportunity to fit the data to a known curve set with the correct behavior.